# stringWithFormat cuts off after %@

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm somewhat new to this, but I have created a stringWithFormat and tried to put two variables into it, but the string cuts off after the first `%@`. Here's the code...

```
cell.authorView.text = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"By %@  |  %@", [item author], [item category]]uppercaseString];
```

I've tried taking out the second variable, but anything I add after the first `%@`, variable or not, cuts off. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's `authorView`? An `UILabel` with ONE line? Does `[item author]` have an extra `\n` at the end?

Comment: Maybe the text is too long to be clipped by the label.

Comment: atfirst try to nslog your [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"By %@  |  %@", [item author], [item category]]uppercaseString] and check the string

Comment: Thanks. It was kicking onto the next line without me realizing it. I have no idea where the line break is, but that's the issue.

Comment: @schmorgledorf change the label backgroundColor to something visible. red or something. It might just be that the label is too small to fit the text.

Comment: If you break the statement into two steps, first creating the string and second setting the label to the string it is easy to debug the problem in lldb or with a `NSLog()`. There is really no penalty, just more readable and testable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the label, that displays the text.
1) Text can contain `\n` and the label linesCount can be set to 1 (In this case only first line will be visible).
2) Text can be too long, and label cuts the string.

So the problem is in label, you can check that string is OK, via

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"By %@  |  %@", [item author], [item category]]uppercaseString]);
```

Comment: This is what the issue is. I have no idea where the break \n (it isn't in the RSS feed I'm drawing from) is from, but that is what's happening. Thanks!